# How can I stop text from being selected and causing the background to be blue?

Tags: html

I can I prevent text from being selectable and making the background blue? The blue background caused by it is the main issue, but preventing the text from being selected can be done if it removes the blue background.

Example:  [image: This is an example from the internet]

Comment: Consider changing the selection color instead.  It's often useful to be able to select and copy text.  To perform a web search on a term you use, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `user-select: none;`.
For full support use:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7mfbk1o8/